# Why ActiveSupport::Concern retuns NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

I have a small application and in order to avoid code duplication I used ActiveSupport::Concern, but something is wrong and I constantly receive the message:

```
NoMethodError in Private::MessagesController#index

undefined method `get_messages' for #<Private::MessagesController:0x00007f644687de88>
```

The application run on

```
Rails version             5.2.2;
Ruby version              2.5.3-p105 (x86_64-linux);
RubyGems version          2.7.6;
Rack version              2.0.6
```

in: controllers/concerns/messages.rb

```
require 'active_support/concern'
module Messages
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def get_messages(conversation_type, messages_amount)
  ....
  end
end
```

in controllers/private/messages_controller.rb

```
class Private::MessagesController < ActionController::Base
  include Messages
  def index
    get_messages('private', 10)
    ....
  end 
end
```

I made a lot of researches but I didn't managed to fix the issue.

As alternative, I moved the

```
def get_messages(conversation_type, messages_amount)
```

into controllers/private/messages_controller.rb and it seems to work, but I want to use exact same method in another controller so, it would be better if I'll manage to use it with ActiveSupport::Concern

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

I renamed module "Messages" to "Messageable" (and the associated files) and it's ok now.

Comment: Do you have another module called `Messages` somewhere?

Comment: yes, I have: models/private/messages.rb 

`class Private::Message < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'private_messages'
  ...
end`

Comment: Does `include ::Messages` help? BTW, generally, your concerns would have longer names to help avoid conflicts and overlaps, maybe you should be saying `include PrivateMessageUtilities` or even `include PrivateMessageControllerUtilities`, there's no need for brevity when naming these sorts of modules.

Comment: `module Messages` exist only in `app/controllers/concerns/messages.rb`. So, what I'm trying to do is to use concerns only with controllers. As you see on my post, I tried to use those 2 controllers: `controllers/concerns/messages.rb` and `controllers/private/messages_controller.rb`. I understood that concerns can be used like this with controllers, right?

Comment: Concerns are just modules with a bit of help with the boilerplate code so yes, this is how you use them. I'm just saying that you seem to have a naming problem so `include Messages` isn't using the `Messages` module that you think it is.

Comment: Yes, indeed. You're right. I renamed it to "Messageable" and it's ok now. Thank you!